# not connecting to mysql in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am querying mysql through java and i am getting the output.

In the middle, I have

```
WHERE 
    ipaddress = 'moteid6'
AND datetime BETWEEN '2012-09-25 15:45:00' AND '2012-09-25 18:45:00'
```

But when I give the datetime1 instead of 2012-09-25 15:45:00 and datetime2 instead of 2012-09-25 18:45:00 and moteid instead of moteid6 like user input ie.,

```
System.out.println("Enter datetime1 in the format YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
Scanner keyboard1 = new Scanner(System.in);
datetime1 = keyboard1.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter datetime2 in the format YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
Scanner keyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);
datetime2 = keyboard2.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter moteid");
Scanner keyboard3 = new Scanner(System.in);
datetime2 = keyboard3.nextLine();
```

and then querying mysql by replacing datetime1 instead of 2012-09-25 15:45:00 ,likewise datetime2 and moteid instead of moteid6,It is taking the inputs but not querying mysql
The result i am getting is

```
run:
Error: null
Enter datetime1 in the format YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
2012-09-25 15:45:00
Enter datetime2 in the format YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
2012-09-25 18:45:00
Enter moteid
moteid6
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 30 seconds)
The query i'm giving is 
String sql = ("SELECT (b.l2framessent - a.l2framessent) AS netl2framessent,CONVERT(endOfInterval*500, DATETIME) endOfInterval FROM (SELECT datetime DIV 500 startOfInterval,l2framessent FROM Statistics3,(SELECT MIN(datetime) mindate FROM Statistics3 WHERE ipaddress='moteid' AND datetime BETWEEN 'datetime1' AND 'datetime2' GROUP BY datetime DIV 500) b WHERE ipaddress='moteid' AND datetime = mindate) a, (SELECT datetime DIV 500 endOfInterval, l2framessent FROM Statistics3, (SELECT MIN(datetime) mindate FROM Statistics3 WHERE ipaddress = 'moteid' AND datetime BETWEEN 'datetime1' AND 'datetime2' GROUP BY datetime DIV 500) b WHERE ipaddress = 'moteid'AND datetime = mindate) b WHERE endOfInterval = startOfInterval+ 1 ");
```

Comment: Could you also show the java code snippet where you are preparing the statement to execute the query?

Comment: Also, you don't need to create a new scanner every time. Just keep using `keyboard1.nextLine()`.

Comment: @Vikdor i have edited in the question,have kept the query i am giving

Comment: @Tim Lamballais Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get your question right, you wanna pass variable names in your select query like this:

```
     WHERE 
    ipaddress = 'moteid6 '
AND datetime BETWEEN 'datetime1' AND 'datetime2'
```

you have to put your dates and strings inside quotes.

i dint go thru the whole query but this seems to be wrong

```
   "(SELECT (b.l2framessent - a.l2framessent) AS netl2framessent,CONVERT(endOfInterval*500, DATETIME) 
endOfInterval FROM (SELECT datetime DIV 500 startOfInterval,l2framessent FROM Statistics3,
(SELECT MIN(datetime) mindate FROM Statistics3 WHERE ipaddress='moteid' AND datetime BETWEEN '"+datetime1+"' AND '"+datetime2+"' 
GROUP BY datetime DIV 500) b WHERE ipaddress='"+moteid+"' AND datetime = mindate) a, 
(SELECT datetime DIV 500 endOfInterval, l2framessent FROM Statistics3, (SELECT MIN(datetime) mindate FROM Statistics3 WHERE 
ipaddress = '"+moteid+"' AND datetime BETWEEN '"+datetime1+"' AND '"+datetime2+"' GROUP BY datetime DIV 500) b WHERE 
ipaddress = '"+moteid+"'AND datetime = mindate) b WHERE endOfInterval = startOfInterval+ 1 ");
```

Comment: i have kept them in quotes know

Comment: @user1659213 can you post your JDBC code . and whats the Error :Null in your first line. if possible post the code before getting the input from the scanner

Comment: try {
            Class.forName(fileReader.getdriver());
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + fileReader.gethost() + ":" + fileReader.getDBport() + "/" + fileReader.getdbname();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, fileReader.getusername(), fileReader.getpasswd());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: ok,But this query worked fine when the gave like 2012-09-25 15:45:00 instead of datetime1 and likewise for datetime2.I dont know why its not working fine now

Comment: it worked,before you said.Ihave tried and got it.But,Thanks a lot.you said to put quotes know,i was trying for those and then i got it.Thankyou